# How can I produce a function with maxima at given locations

Tags: functions

At the first I ask a general question and after that I bring out the special problem.

If we have some functions such as f1[x], f2[x], f3[x] and f4[x] and they have shared intersections points. Is there possible to find a smooth and analytic g[x] function (with special combination of f1.....f4) whose maxima be the last intersections points.

Practically,

```
f1[x_]:=Sqrt[(37 + 24 Cos[x/2] + 8 Cos[(3 x)/2] + 3 Cos[2 x]) Sin[ x]^2]/(6 Sqrt[2]);
f2[x_]:=Sqrt[(710 + 1024 Cos[x/2] + 487 Cos[x] + 208 Cos[(3 x)/2] + 106 Cos[2 x] + 48 Cos[(5 x)/2] + 9 Cos[3 x]) Sin[x/ 4]^4]/(9 Sqrt[2]);
f3[x_]:=4/9 Sqrt[(7 + 8 Cos[x/2] + 3 Cos[x])^2 Sin[x/4]^8];
f4[x_]:=2/3 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(Cos[x/4] + Cos[(3 x)/4])^2 (7 + 8 Cos[x/2] + 3 Cos[x]) Sin[x/4]^6];
```

here the plot of them[image]
obviously, the intersections approximately take place at x=5 and x=7.5.
Although the summation of those functions (fsum=f1+f2+f3+f4) presents maxima at the intersections but fsum is not derivative and is not analytic also it has secondary maxima . I am searching a function just has primary maxima at the intersections and doesn't have any other secondary maxima and be derivative.[image]

Comment: Firstly, the two intersection points you find are only approximately intersections of all four functions, but you can find that point numerically.  But what do you mean the function has to be derivative?  I don't see how `g[x]` could be some linear combination of the `fn` functions and only have one maximum.

Comment: Yes you are right (approximately intersections). Not necessity to linear combinations. As a mater of fact, any function that be able to satisfy our conditions is desired.

Comment: You can get the x-coordinate for the approximate intersection via `NMinimize[{Norm[{f1[x] - f2[x], f1[x] - f3[x], f1[x] - f4[x], 
      f2[x] - f3[x], f2[x] - f4[x], f3[x] - f4[x]}], #1 < x < #2}, 
   x] & @@@ {{4, 6}, {6, 8}}` but as to how to generate a function with two and only two maxima at distinct locations, I'm not sure really

Comment: Please explain what you mean by the "last intersection points" and by "the function must be derivative".

Comment: @MarcoB, by "last intersection points" I mean the intersection of all four graphs with each others. Derivative: d g[x]/dx must be defined. For instance, f1+f2+f3+f4 in the above example is not derivative on aproximately x= 3, 6, 9. (the left derivative is not equal to the right derivative.)

Comment: @MarcoB. I think the OP means that the function needs to be differentiable at those points (and probably everywhere).

Comment: @march, Yes, exactly you are true.

Comment: It's easy to find a function with maxima at specified points $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$. Here's one: $-(x-x_1)^2(x-x_2)^2\cdots(x-x_n)^2$.

Comment: @Rahul, but this function exactly must be related to 4 previous functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should rephrase the question. There seem to be a couple of questions here. First, the intersection points - there are two real intersection points, where all four functions are equal at x=0 and x=4 Pi, and there are two approximate intersection points which you can find numerically.

Here is one method to find those approximate intersections

```
NMinimize[{Norm[{f1[x] - f2[x], f1[x] - f3[x], f1[x] - f4[x],
       f2[x] - f3[x], f2[x] - f4[x], f3[x] - f4[x]}], #1 < x < #2}, 
   x] & @@@ {{4, 6}, {6, 8}}
{p1, p2} = %[[;; , 2, 1, 2]]
(* {{0.0363041, {x -> 4.94581}}, {0.0363041, {x -> 7.62056}}} *)
(* {4.94581, 7.62056} *)
```

Then, once you have those points, you have the problem of finding a function with maxima at those points.  (I took the liberty of rephrasing your question title to emphasize this point)

Well, one method is to impose the constraint that the function has a zero derivative at those points (and I suppose it should have a minima right in the middle as well).  For a polynomial answer, you can just integrate the cubic function whose zeroes are at those points, and then add a constant to make sure it crosses the points you need it to

```
quarticfunc = Integrate[(x - x1) (x2 - x) (x - x3), x]
quarticfunc = quarticfunc /. {x1 -> p1, x2 -> Mean[{p1, p2}], x3 -> p2}
meanval = Mean[Through[{f1, f2, f3, f4}[p1]]]
quarticfunc = quarticfunc + meanval - (quarticfunc /. x -> p1)
Grid[{{Plot[quarticfunc /. x -> z, {z, 0, 4 π}], 
   Plot[quarticfunc /. x -> z, {z, 0, 4 π}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]}}]

(* -(1/12) x (3 x^3 - 12 x1 x2 x3 - 4 x^2 (x1 + x2 + x3) + 
   6 x (x2 x3 + x1 (x2 + x3))) *)
(* -(1/12) x (-2841.75 + 699.88 x - 75.3982 x^2 + 3 x^3) *)
(* 0.499757 *)
(* -354.631 - 1/12 x (-2841.75 + 699.88 x - 75.3982 x^2 + 3 x^3) *)
```

[image]

The function is not pretty, but it meets your rather odd requirements.  Now plot it with your other functions,

```
Show[Plot[Evaluate@Through[{f1, f2, f3, f4}[x]], {x, 0, 4 \[Pi]}],
 Plot[quarticfunc /. x -> z, {z, 0, 4 \[Pi]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.0075], Dashed}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Besides so much thanks for your affair, what is your comment about this:  we write g=a*f1+b*f2+c*f3+d*f4 (a,b,c,d are factors), in {x1=4.94581,x2= 7.62056} there are two maxima then:  D[g]/dx(x=x1)=0 and D[g]/dx(x=x2)=0 as maxima and D[g]/dx(x=(x1+x2)/2)=0 (mean value of x1 and x2 is minima) therefore there are three (3) equations to find 4 factors (a,b,c,d) if I can find another equation I can find factors and thus find 'g'?!! It this method correct?

Comment: It is possible that would find the function, but what is to stop it from having other minima and maxima at other places?